# The same color shows up differently for JButton and JFrame. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency, jbutton

[image]

The following code produces the above image. As you can see, the same color pink shows up differently for the JFrame than for the JButton. What fix can I make so they are exactly the same color?

```
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

    public class Testing extends JFrame {   
        public Testing() {
            super("hi");
            setBackground(Color.PINK);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            JButton jb = new JButton();
            jb.setText("Here I am");
            Border line = new LineBorder(Color.PINK);
            Border margin = new EmptyBorder(5, 15, 5, 15);
            Border compound = new CompoundBorder(line, margin);
            jb.setOpaque(true);
            jb.setBorder(compound);
            jb.setBackground(Color.PINK);

            panel.add(jb);
            add(panel);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Testing t = new Testing();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson is it just me or is it the angle of the monitor affecting how the color is perceived ?

Comment: @LittleChild  The angle of my monitor changes *every* color.  OTOH at any angle, those colors seem different.

Comment: I thought the example code I provide is a short, self-contained, correct example? What am I missing?

Comment: An SSCCE of a run-time problem should compile cleanly when copy/pasted into a source file and compiled.  A code snippet (without imports) will not compile.  Hence, a code snippet *cannot be* an SSCCE.  I posted an SSCCE in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set backcolor for your panel instead of frame. problem solved.

```
public Testing() {
    super("hi");
    setBackground(Color.PINK);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton jb = new JButton();
    jb.setText("Here I am");
    Border line = new LineBorder(Color.PINK);
    Border margin = new EmptyBorder(5, 15, 5, 15);
    Border compound = new CompoundBorder(line, margin);
    jb.setOpaque(true);
    jb.setBorder(compound);
    jb.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    panel.add(jb);
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The colors **are** the same but the code was setting the wrong thing pink.  Vis.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ColorTest extends JFrame {

    public ColorTest() {
        super("hi");
        //setBackground(Color.PINK);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        JButton jb = new JButton();
        jb.setText("Here I am");
        Border line = new LineBorder(Color.RED, 5);
        Border margin = new EmptyBorder(5, 15, 5, 15);
        Border compound = new CompoundBorder(line, margin);
        jb.setOpaque(true);
        jb.setBorder(compound);
        jb.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        panel.add(jb);
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColorTest t = new ColorTest();
    }
}
```

### Also

1. Don't extend frame, just use an instance of one.
2. Swing GUIs should be started & updated on the EDT.